# IIS 5.1: Programmatically Create Virtual Sub-Directory

Tags: iis, vbscript, automation

**Background**

I'm trying to automate the creation of Virtual Directories based on the location of an existing Virtual Directory and its sub-directories.

Example:

C:\WebSites\Parent\NewVirtualDirectories

Where Parent is a Virtual Directory and NewVirtualDirectories contains any automated Virtual Directories.

**Problem**

Using the following Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim args, strComputer, strVdirName, strVdirPath, objVdir, objIIS, objWebSite

Set args = WScript.Arguments

strComputer = "localhost" 
strVdirName = args(1) 
strVdirPath = args(0) 

Set objIIS = GetObject("IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC/1") 
Set objWebSite = objIIS.GetObject("IISWebVirtualDir","Root/Parent") 
Set objVdir = objWebSite.Create("IISWebVirtualDir",strVdirName) 
objVdir.AccessRead = True 
objVdir.Path = strVdirPath 
objVdir.AppCreate (True) 
objVdir.SetInfo 

WScript.Quit
```

I can create children under Parent, but they show up Directly under the parent. I need them to be in the Sub Folder.

I get: http://localhost/Parent/NewSite

I want: http://localhost/Parent/NewVirtualDirectories/NewSite

I've tried

```
Set objWebSite = objIIS.GetObject("IISWebVirtualDir","Root/Parent/NewVirtualDirectories")
```

but NewVirtualDirectories is not a Virtual Directory (an I don't want it to be) so I get an error. I can get the desired effect when I do this manually in IIS manager, but I can't figure out how to automate it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

For those who are facing similar problems, I found a great resource for VBScript-ing

http://www.cruto.com/resources/vbscript/vbscript-examples/vbscript-sitemap.asp

---

After doing a lot more digging (trial and error) I was able to figure it out.

By referencing the existing folder as a **IISWebDirectory**, I was able to select it and then create an application without creating a virtual directory.

```
Option Explicit
Dim args, strComputer, strVdirName, strVdirPath, objVdir, objIIS, objWebSite

Set args = WScript.Arguments

strComputer = "localhost" 
strVdirName = args(1) 
strVdirPath = args(0) 

Set objIIS = GetObject("IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC/1") 
Set objVdir = objIIS.GetObject("IISWebDirectory","Root/Parent/NewVirtualDirectories/" + strVdirName)
objVdir.AccessRead = True 
objVdir.AccessScript = True 
objVdir.AppFriendlyName = strVdirName 
objVdir.AppCreate (True) 
objVdir.SetInfo 

WScript.Quit
```